# Pros and cons of supercapacitors in defibrillator

Tags: supercapacitor, waveform

Basically I wonder about pros and cons of using super capacitors in defibrillator. It is known that 1.5 - 7 kV signal with duration from 1 to 200 ms is applied. The energy should not be more 200 J.
Also, some constraints like no ordinary batteries on board, low current source to charge capacitors (it's a 'natural' power source like microbial fuel cell, just about 0.2Amps@0.7Volts per cell).
Also I am not sure if the capacitors can be used to be  dishcarged into load or we have to do some transformations in circuit.

Thank you for any hints and clarification.

Comment: What's going to charge your capacitors and why would you not use that directly?

Comment: Compare 7kV or even 1.5kV with the voltage rating of a supercapacitor.

Comment: I would look at the effect of equivalent series resistance and the voltage balancing among the huge number of series capacitors needed. How much self discharge would there be due to the voltage balancing arrangement? Compare the alternatives regarding cost, size and weight, complexity and performance.

Comment: @ Transisor  I am not sure at the moment. The capacitors will bу a part of oscillation circuit and charged somehow. Then it will be discharged to the load.

Comment: First of all, can you explain what function would the supercapacitors perform in a defibrillator? Would they replace the existing battery? Or the existing capacitors that are charged up and discharged into the load?

Comment: I think this answer needs improvement... we can assume high voltage generation out of a normal battery will always use capacitors which can store enough energy for the intended application. Please be more specific what kind of usage of the capacitors you have in mind and what kind of constraints you are thinking of? price, lifetime, safety, dimensions, heat, humanity,....

Comment: @ schnedan It is expected that no ordinary batteries on board. The power comes from bio fuel cell. I've corrected the question.

Comment: Use `@username` without a space or your ping won't work. I didn't get a notification.

Comment: What's your goal here?  You're clearly not *building* an *actual* implantable medical device.  If you think you have a novel idea for a prototype that's years away from even animal trials, then *you* sit down and figure out how well it may work, build prototypes and test them on the bench, etc.  And probably you should study the literature on existing solutions.